# Multiple assertions on same value at different points of method

Tags: c#, unit-testing, xamarin

I have a task that I am trying to write a unit test for. When I await the task I need to ensure that the boolean is set to true at the beginning of the task, and then set to false before it completes. I can easily test what the value of the boolean is once the task has completed, but I need to be able to test the value at the beginning.

I've tried some sort of event monitoring using fluent assertions, but that only informs me that the property has been updated, not what the value has been updated to.

```
private bool _boolToTest;
public bool BoolToTest
{
    get => _boolToTest;
        set
        {
            if (SetProperty(ref _boolToTest, value))
            {
                RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(CanExecute));
            }
        }
}

public bool CanExecute => !_boolToTest;

public async Task Foo()
{
    BoolToTest = true;
    var somevalue = await _foo.Bar();
    if (something)
    {
        doSomething();
    }
    BoolToTest = false;
}
```

In a perfect world I would be able to do something like value.Should().BeTrueThenFalse();. I basically need to achieve that.

Comment: Why not just assert it is false at the start, do your work then assert at the end? Though, it seems like you should just set the value at the start to false, rather than assert.

Comment: The wording of this question is confusing to me. I am having a hard time following what is being asked.

Comment: You don't show what `_foo.Bar()` is. If you mock it so that `Bar` returns something like `Task.Delay(100)` you can might be able to monitor how `BoolToTest` changes while `Foo` is executing. But it's weird. This will confuse anyone who looks at it. That figuring out how to test it is confusing is a strong indicator that the code itself is confusing.

Comment: @ScottHannen you're telling me it's confusing. I've been asked to write tests for it all without changing any of the implementation.

Comment: That's fair. I mean, not fair to you. Someone has visited evil upon you by writing confusing, difficult-to-test code (which is the reason why they didn't already write unit tests for it) and asking you to figure out how to test it without changing it. Sometimes that will be next to impossible. But in this case I think it's possible by doing what was described in my previous comment. If you include some more detail - is `_foo` something injected into the this class? - I can give an example.

Comment: @ScottHannen See the answer that I accepted from Fabio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to test it by subscribing to the `PropertyChanged` event.

```
var actualValues = new List<bool> { };

var objectUnderTheTest = new MyObject();
objectUnderTheTest.PropertyChanged += (sender, args) =>
    { 
        var instance = (MyObject)sender;
        if (args.PropertyName == nameof(instance.CanExecute))
        {
            actualValues.Add(instance.BoolToTest);
        }
    }

 await objectUnderTheTest.Foo();

 var expected = new[] { true, false };

 actualValues.Should().BeEquivalentTo(expected, options => options.WithStrictOrdering());
```